# relaunch activity stack

Tags: android, android-activity, call

i have an application with many `Actvities` , i need to call each of those `activities` with paramaters to retrieve data from database or a file , but if i call an activity a second time i dont want that the activity retrieve data again cos it can be boring for users .

Example :

1. i have main activity with menu that can call 3 activities : A,B and C
2. each one of them need parameters to access database
3. in each activity i have a link to navigate between them , i need to
   call back the activities then from stack so no need that they access
   database again.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might wana save Bundle inside onPause().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not finishing your activities, data will persist. You dont have to do anything additional.
Otherwise you can extend Application class and save your data into some data structure there, which you can retrieve any time later.

Comment: the first call of each activity must be by sending extras in order the get data from database , but for the second call of the same activity i want just get it back from stack.
how can i do it ?